# Using CSS display:flex (flexbox) and/or JavaScript to make adjustable page

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, codemirror

I'm making a simple IDE for a educational programming language similar to [Karel the Dog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeHS#Karel_the_Dog). And I have trouble with making base html page.

I have 4 areas:

- Toolbox (for buttons like open, save as, run etc.)
- Field (canvas for drawing executor that can move on the field and do some stuff)
- Code ([CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net) editor for writing executor's commands)
- Console (place where IDE can print messages like compilation errors or runtime debug output)

I wrote what I want from every area in my code so I'll say only what is not working now:

1. The page should fill 100% screen's height.
2. Cannot set CodeMirror to fill all available to its parent height. And when its size is greater than parent's height, scrollbars should appear.
3. The same problem with canvas - but only on vertical.
4. Is there a way to make a separator between code and field areas that can be used to redistribute horizontal space between areas?

There is another difficulty. If the item number 4 requires JavaScript, then I'll ask to help me with solving it with [WinJS 3.0](http://try.buildwinjs.com) library because I won't add to the project jQuery or other heavy stuff only for this resize capability.

So, can anyone help me?

I loaded my code to [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/wwvq7dhv/4/) and pasted it here:

```js
var ce = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('b-codemirror'), {
  value: "\n\n\nIt is CodeMirror element. [PARAMS ALL] " +
    "width: 100% of parent element, height: always 100% of" +
    " parent element + both scrollbars if needed\n\n\n",
  lineNumbers: true
});
var cc = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
cc.font = "16px Helvetica";
cc.fillText("It is canvas. Can be resized from", 10, 30);
cc.fillText("JS. If it is larger than parent element,", 10, 60);
cc.fillText("corresponding scrollbar should appear.", 10, 90);
```

```css
@import url("http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css");

/* overriding default codemirror.css */
.CodeMirror {
  font-family: monospace;
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.b-section {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#b-fieldcode {
  min-height: 640px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row;
  flex-flow: row;
}
#b-toolbox {
  background: #ffeebb;
}
#b-console {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ffeebb;
}
#b-field {
  background: #ccccff;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 40%;
  flex: 1 1 40%;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  order: 1;
}
#b-code {
  background: #dddd88;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 60%;
  flex: 1 1 60%;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  order: 2;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #b-fieldcode, #page {
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    flex-flow: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #b-code, #b-field {
    -webkit-order: 0;
    order: 0;
  }
  #b-field, #b-code {
    height: 500px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<div id="b-toolbox" class="b-section">
  Here comes the space for buttons.
  [PARAMS ALL] width: 100% of screen, height: sized to content
</div>
<div id="b-fieldcode">
  <div id="b-field" class="b-section">
    Here comes canvas wrapper.<br />
    [PARAMS landscape] width: flex 40% of screen, height:
    100% of screen minus b-toolbox and b-console.
    <br />[PARAMS portrait] width: 100% of
    screen, height: fixed 400px.<br />
    <canvas width="300" height="300" id="canvas"
            style="background-color: green" />
  </div>
  <div id="b-code" class="b-section">
    Here comes CodeEditor wrapper.<br />
    [PARAMS landscape] width: flex 60% of screen, height:
    100% of screen minus b-toolbox and b-console.<br />
    [PARAMS portrait] width: 100% of
    screen, height: fixed 500px.
    <div id="b-codemirror"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="b-console" class="b-section">
  Here comes output console.
  [PARAMS ALL] width: 100% of screen, height: fixed 120px.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to split styles for portrait and landscape. For portrait part, that's simple easy, so let's skip it.

For landspace part, you need a fluid height header (buttons) and a fixed height footer (console). This is a typical use case of css flex - all spare space are going to main part. So you just set `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` to <body> and `flex: 1;` to the main part (#fieldcode in your snippet).

Then #field occupies 40% width of #fieldcode, and #code ocuppies 60%. So again, you set `display: flex; flex-direction: row;` to #fieldcode, and `flex: 4;` to #field, `flex: 6;` to #code, so that spare space of #fieldcode is separated as 4:6. But please note the difference from previous. Yes, the `flex-direction` value is different. That tells the browser either to separate horizontally, or vertically.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#toolbox {
  background: #feb;
}
#field {
  background: #ccf;
  overflow: auto;
}
#code {
  background: #dd8;
  overflow: auto;
}
#codemirror {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#console {
  background: #feb;
  height: 120px;
}

@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  #field {
    height: 400px;
  }
  #code {
    height: 500px;
  }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #fieldcode {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  #field {
    flex: 4;
  }
  #code {
    flex: 6;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="toolbox">buttons here</div>

<div id="fieldcode">
  <div id="field">
    <canvas></canvas>
  </div>

  <div id="code">
    <div id="codemirror"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="console">console here</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for four day delay with answer. It seems that using flexbox is much more simple than I thought. Thank you very much!

Comment: According to W3C spec, actually `flex` is born to deal with web layout. Before that we use `position`, `float` or other techniques to achive the layout we want, however they are **semantically** not aiming for layout problems. It's because HTML goes so fast that we want to do so much more with it than just present plain text, at the same time spec was left far behind. So technically, before `flex` we are just **hacking** layout, no matter how neat they seem to be. :D